# See who has logged into a Heap.io account?

Tags: heap-analytics

With Heap Analytics is there a way of seeing which users have logged into an account? I mean logged into heapanalytics.com rather than the client facing app / website.

Answer (score 1):

The UI doesn't offer a feature like this but if you reach out to support they can give you a report that will tell you who has logged in and when.